# Finding CDF of a distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution on a line segment $[-3, 3]$ and $Y=X^2$. Find cdf of the variable $Y$. The answer is: 
$$F_Y(t)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{t}/3& \text{ for}\,\, t\in[0,9) \\
1 & \text{ for } t\ge9\end{cases}$$
I mean why do we change those "boundaries" why we have distribution on $[-3,3]$ and then we change it into $[0,9]$?

Comment: On $[-3,0]$, $x^2$ is decreasing, so if $x \in [-3,0]$ then $x^2 \in [0,(-3)^2]=[0,9]$. On $[0,3]$, $x^2$ is increasing, so if $x \in [0,3]$ then $x^2 \in [0,3^2]=[0,9]$. The rest of the CDF just says that $X^2 \in [0,9]$ with probability 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y$ takes values in $[-3,3]$ then $X=Y^2$ takes values in $[0,9]$.

Comment: But it's not simple elementary operation i do not find this answer useful.

Comment: @mkropkowski Leave the calculation of the cdf aside. That is not elementary. But you asked about the domain and that is an elementary calculation. When $Y=-3$ or $Y=3$ then $X=Y^2=9$. And the minimum of $X$ is attained when $Y=0$, so is also $0$.

Comment: This is the most reputation/word valuable accepted answer I have seen until now and I decided to contribute to that ratio :D